# Android Studio newProject Stuck at gradle project info

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I recently installed Android Studio. Trying to create new Project but it got stuck here.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPA9B.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your gradle is dependency not resolved, try setting the proxy in Android Studio by following steps and retry with build.

To set the HTTP proxy settings in Android Studio:

1. From the menu bar, click File > Settings (on a Mac, click Android Studio > Preferences).
2. In the left pane, click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy.